# Why getProperties method is not present in the Ember namespace?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been reading about the methods in the [Ember namespace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#methods) and I was not able to find the method `getProperties` which I know exists. On searching I found the method in [Ember Instrumentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html#method_getProperties) namespace. But, I was able to find the [setProperties](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_setProperties) method in [Ember Namespace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html).

Is there a reason why `getProperties` method is defined in the [Ember Instrumentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html) namespace rather than [Ember namespace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in one of the pages, it's accidentally including `getProperties` with instrumentation, it's really part of Ember Metal.

https://github.com/emberjs/website/tree/master/source/api

Comment: Thanks. Found it in ember-metal as you said - [https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/get_properties.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/get_properties.js)